# Azure build pipeline: avoid duplicate run for merge

Tags: azure-pipelines

I've got Azure DevOps set up so that every push to every branch triggers a build, and every PR requires a successful built to be merged.

However, pushing to a branch that has a PR triggers two builds:

- one for the commit to the branch, and
- another for the PR.

Obviously, these builds are building the same thing.
I've had to put in a number of conditions

```
condition: and( succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge'))
```

for example because I want pre-release NuGet packages produced for the branch (with the branch name in the pre-release tag) but not for the merge.

Can the merge jsut use the build for the branch instead of triggering a pointless duplicate? (This is how GitLab works.)

Answer (score 0):

> Can the merge jsut use the build for the branch instead of triggering a pointless duplicate? (This is how GitLab works.)

You could add the condition for the pipeline with [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml): `Build.Reason`：

```
condition: and( succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'))
```

Please check the document [Run for continuous integration (CI) builds if succeeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#run-for-continuous-integration-ci-builds-if-succeeding) for some more details.

Comment: The PR still needs a build because that is a condition on it. I want it to use the build that was done for the push instead of wasting time on a separate build that is identical.